# c# script not able to overwrite my global variable inside a function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I hope you can answer this question. I think it's really easy, but I'm stuck.  I have a function called "CalcTransition". It calculates the remaining time of a transition for me. But my global variable "time" is never overwritten. It stays at zero. Anyone have any idea?

Here the full code:

```
    float duration = 1.0f;
    float startTime;
    float time;

    string lastTrigger = null;

    float TransitionTwoValues(float minVal,float maxVal){
        float vTemp = maxVal;
        maxVal = minVal;
        minVal = vTemp;

        return Mathf.SmoothStep(minVal,maxVal,time);
    }

    void ResetStartTimeOnce(string currentTriggerName,string lastTriggerName){
        if(currentTriggerName != lastTrigger){
            lastTrigger = lastTriggerName;
            startTime = Time.time;
        }
    }
    void CalcTransition(){
        time = (Time.time - startTime) / duration;
    }

    void Focus(){
        duration = 0.1f;
        ResetStartTimeOnce("FocusOn", lastTrigger);
        CalcTransition();

        _Vignette.intensity.value  = TransitionTwoValues( vignetteMaxVal, vignetteMinVal);
        _MotionBlur.intensity.value = TransitionTwoValues(motionBlurMaxVal,motionBlurMinVal);
        _ColorAdjustment.saturation.value = TransitionTwoValues(colorSaturationMaxVal,colorSaturationMinVal);
    }
    void FocusRelease(){
        duration = 0.5f;
        ResetStartTimeOnce("FocusOff", lastTrigger);
        CalcTransition();

        _Vignette.intensity.value  = TransitionTwoValues( vignetteMinVal, vignetteMaxVal);
        _MotionBlur.intensity.value = TransitionTwoValues(motionBlurMinVal,motionBlurMaxVal);
        _ColorAdjustment.saturation.value = TransitionTwoValues(colorSaturationMinVal,colorSaturationMaxVal);
    }

    void Update(){

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)){
            Focus();
            Debug.Log(time); //** TIME ALWAYS 0 WHY?
        }

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1)){
            FocusRelease();
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: debug your code to make sure the code paths that assign to `time` are actually run.

Comment: Maybe it *is* overwritten.. with 0. Check the values; for all we know Time.time might be 0, meaning `0-0 / anything` is 0

Comment: Hey thank for your reply :) I think you are right. I'm freezing the GameSpeed/Time in an other script so that could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Time is always zero because you calculate it ONCE in the frame (Update) of `MouseDown`, then never touch it again until the next time you recalculate it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for you reply. I have taken your answer into account and tried "GetMouseButton" but without success.